# The day of the week does not print out but my price, entree, and calories do print out

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        dailyMenu [,] daysOfMonth = new dailyMenu[4,5];
        for (int column = 0; column < daysOfMonth.GetLength(0); column++) 
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < daysOfMonth.GetLength(1); row++) 
            {
                dailyMenu dm = new dailyMenu ();
                daysOfMonth[column,row] = dm; 
                Console.WriteLine (dm.ToString ());
            }
        } 
    } 
 static string [] daysOfWeek= {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
 public dailyMenu()
        {
            assignDate();
            GetDay();
            RandPopulate();
        }
        void assignDate()
        {
            date = initalDate;
            initalDate++;
            if (GetDay()== daysOfWeek[4]) 
            {
                initalDate += 2;
            }
        }
 public string GetDay() 
        { 
            return daysOfWeek [(date % 7)]; 
        }
```

//Here's all the relevant code. This is what prints out for example, " Day of Week: System.String[], Entree= Beef Willington, price" 8.99, Calories: 1200

Comment: You need to show the `ToString` override for `dm` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is in the `public override void ToString()` Method of your `dailyMenu`. The result:

```
Day of Week: System.String[], Entree= Beef Willington, price" 8.99, Calories: 1200
```

Shows that you actually printing `daysOfWeek` (which is a `string[]`) rather than the *element* of `daysOfWeek` to `string` (something like `daysOfWeek[0]` (note the `0`))

To get it right, try to print out the *element* of the `daysOfWeek` rather than doing `daysOfWeek.ToString()` in your `public override void ToString()` method

Comment: I'm tryingto ge it to invoke the method i used to get a day in the static array i have above

Comment: Ah yes, please show your current code implementation, especially the `ToString()` for your `dailyMenu` - it is very important piece to know what's wrong

Comment: public string GetDay() 
   { 
    return daysOfWeek [(date % 7)]; 
   }public override string ToString ()
   {
    return string.Format ("Day of week: " +daysOfWeek[] + ", Entree: " + entree + ", Price: " + price + ", Calories: " + calories);
   }

Comment: I want it to get a day from the GetDay method

Comment: ah, there the problem is: you use `"Day of week: " + daysOfWeek[]"` while you should use `"Day of week: " + GetDay() + ..."` instead

Comment: Nvm i just figured it out by myself :D

Comment: @NnachetaNnyagu exactly... you seem to figure it out. ;) great!